# django print value of query set

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

simple problem (i think).
I have following query:

```
hostname = Host.objects.get(pk=(host_id))
env = Host.objects.filter(cfthostname=hostname).values('cftos')
print(env)
```

what i get from print is:

```
<QuerySet [{'cftos': 'unix'}]>
```

how to make it:

```
unix
```

Comment: have your tried **`env[0]['cftos']`**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
instance = Host.objects.filter(cfthostname=hostname).values('cftos')[0]
env = instance['cftos']
```

Also, if you're only getting one value, you can use [flat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) like below to do this in one line:

```
env = Host.objects.filter(cfthostname=hostname).values_list('cftos', flat=True)[0]
```

Comment: yea, only one value.
Simple and easy solution! thanks

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Host.objects.filter(cfthostname=hostname).values('cftos')
```

returns a query, if you want data use:

```
Host.objects.filter(cfthostname__exact=hostname).values_list('cftos', flat=True)
```

or if you have only one result:

```
Host.objects.get(cfthostname__exact=hostname).cftos

Host.objects.filter(cfthostname=hostname).values().last()['cftos']
```